# Why is a service being started if it isn't mentioned in /etc/init.d?

Tags: services, init, systemd, system-v

After a clean install of Fedora 17 and `distcc-server`, I did a `service distccd start`, which completed successfully.

`man service` indicates that it would merely be running the `distccd` script at `/etc/init.d/distccd`, but that file doesn't exist.  `chkconfig` also doesn't appear to know about `distccd`, which is confirmed by there being no related files in `/etc/rc[0-6].d`.  There *does* exist a file `/etc/sysconfig/distccd` that contains run options for the distcc daemon, but I can't seem to find anything linking `service` to `/etc/sysconfig` anyway.

How does `service` know what to do when I type `service distccd start`?

Also, I have learned that Fedora 17 may redirect `service` to `systemd`/`systemctl`.  Even if that is the case, I still don't find any `distccd` related files in `/etc/systemd/{system,user}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/systemd` is for user defined services. The default location for system defined services is `/lib/systemd/system/`. You can overwrite system defined services in `/etc/systemd`.

For more information about systemd either have a look at the [fedora wiki page for systemd](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd) or have a look at the [systemd documentation](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-docs.html)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `service` relies on an init script being present in `/etc/init.d`.

distccd may not have come packaged with an init script.  Try the following to start the service as a daemon:

`distccd --daemon`

If that works, you can create your own script at `/etc/init.d/distccd` that fires the above command, then you'll be able to treat it like a system service with `service distccd start`.  Use `/etc/init.d/skeleton` as a template.

Comment: I have updated the question title to better reflect this, but I am seeing that distccd is actually being started with a `service distccd start`, even though there is no file `/etc/init.d/distccd`.  So I am asking how that is happening, not how to make it happen.

Comment: strange.  try an strace on it and see if you get an idea of where service is looking.   `strace -o test.txt service distccd start`

Comment: @Banjer fedora uses systemd in the latest version, so it probably uses a definition in `/lib/systemd/`